# WCF Get request returns 401 after successfully processed the request

Tags: c#, wcf

I have added a new svc file to an existing WCF service. When I make request to the newly added service its getting executed without any issues and while returning the response it throws below 401 response.

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 13 Mar 2017 17:49:05 GMT
Content-Length: 6441
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

Below is my truncated web config

```
<services>
      .....
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Loc.Company.Service.Behavior" name="Loc.Company.WCFService.REST.AzureService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Loc.Company.EndPoint.RestBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Loc.Company.Service.Binding.WebHttpBinding" contract="Loc.Company.BusinessService.V2.WCFContracts.IAzureService" />
      </service>
    </services>
```

The service endpoints which was previously there are working fine without any issues.

Also since the error occurs once the WCF method completes the execution Im not able to debug further to find the actual Issue.

Can someone please let me know what could be the cause for this. Is there anyway I can debug further?

Comment: Generally, failures after processing successfully indicate either a failure in custom message handlers or a serialization issue. What does the new API you've exposed return ?

Comment: It currently returns a Nested Objects with 2 dozens params, Let me check and see if that is the case. but the errormessage seems totally different right.